# Why is short circuiting not working in python's "all" function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to check a number of conditions using python's `all()` function.

My understanding is that this code short circuits so, as soon as it evaluates a condition as `False` the function also returns `False`. If that understanding is correct then can someone explain the below:

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = None
>>> all([a is None, b])
False
>>> all([a is None, b, "text" in b])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
>>> b = {"text": "Text I'm looking for"}
>>> all([a is None, b, "text" in b])
True
```

The first time I run `all()` shows that it correctly evaluates to `False` so why, if I add another test, does this break? Have I misunderstood how short circuiting works?

I've tested this in python 3.8.3 and python 2.7.18 with the same outcome.

Comment: Constructing the list has to evaluate all the values in your list, before `all` can then check the list (with short-circuiting cutting that checking short at the first False)

Comment: The argument *to* `all` is evaluated before `all` is called.

Comment: `[a is None, b, "text" in b]` is a list.  All of the elements are evaluated in the process of creating this list.  All of this happens before it can be passed to `all()`, so no short-circuiting is even possible here.

Comment: Short-circuiting can only happen if the argument to `all` is a generator.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I've been using python long enough that I should have worked that one out...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with `all`. You're creating a list literal, which will evaluate its contents before being passed to `all`:

```
>>> [a is None, b, "text" in b]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterables
```

If you want this to work as you expect, you need a lazier structure than a list:

```
a = None
b = None

def lazy():  # A lazy generator
    yield a is None
    yield b
    yield "text" in b

>>> all(lazy())
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Evaluation of expressions are being done. Thats the reason you're getting such output.

See this:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(): return all([True, False ,3 == 2])
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (all)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              8 LOAD_CONST               4 (2)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             12 BUILD_LIST               3
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```